# Установка даты и времени в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Как в клиентском приложении изменить дату/время на сервере с помощью `T-SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у клиента есть права на это - через процедуру `xp_cmdshell`.